# Android multiple shortcuts

Tags: java, android, android-intent, shortcut

This link: http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2010/android-adding-desktop-shortcut-support-to-your-app/ teaches me how to create a shortcut to any of my app's activities. However, when you look at your phone's shortcuts list, you see that apps like settings have a whole bunch of shortcuts. So there's my question: How do you add multiple shortcuts to the shortcut list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many shortcuts for an App, as many public intents are declared in its manifest. The Activity in example is returning only one Intent and finishing on the spot. You can have your Shortcut Activity show a list of all available intents of your app and return that intent in its result.

Comment: I don't really understand. You can pass just 1 intent to the `setResult()`method right?

Comment: @Merlin Yep, but which one ? that you can make this Activity ask you, like show a dialog or something.